# Using two line application name causes strange character

Tags: android, special-characters

I'm trying to deploy android app with two lines on it's name, using '\n'.
thing is, part of the devices shows the two lines correctly while others shows strange character instead - 口.

I'm guessing it's related to the device character set. 
Is there a generic way to cause a new line on all devices?

Thanks.

Comment: No, I'm not changing any fonts, it's the default...